# как сделать grid сетку адаптивной? как уменьшать ее содержимое?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

у меня есть грид сетка - товары в магазине, и на большом экране с ней все хорошо, но когда экран уменьшается вслед за ним уменьшается только ширина ячеек сетки, из-за чего элементы наезжают друг на друга. Мне нужно как то уменьшать размеры(и шир. и выс.) ячейки и ее содержимого вместе с уменьшением ширины экрана. Как это сделать?

```
<div class="content">    <!--сама сетка-->
<a class="block-link" href="#"> <div class="block-1">       <!--блок с товаром-->
        <div class="item-image" style="background-image: url(res/medium_12__1_.webp)"></div>
        <div class="item-info">Example-phone M27 Lite 10RAM 9REM 0gb memory.</div>
        <div class="item-buy">
            <div class="old-price">1039,5$</div>
            <span class="price">957,34$</span>
            <button style="background-image: url(res/mini-ico/in-cart.png)"></button>
            </div>
    </div> </a>
    <a class="block-link" href="#"> <div class="block-1">    <!--2 блок с товаром-->
        <div class="item-image" style="background-image: url(res/medium_11__1_.webp)"></div>
        <div class="item-info">Another Example-phone HTN-14.12</div>
        <div class="item-buy">
            <div class="old-price">1102,4$</div>
            <span class="price">992,75$</span>
            <button style="background-image: url(res/mini-ico/in-cart.png)"></button>
        </div>
    </div> </a>

.content{
    margin-left: 0.9%;
    margin-top: 1.1%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr repeat(3, 50.3%);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 16.1%);
    grid-column-gap: 0.4%;
    grid-row-gap: 3.3%;
}
.block-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.block-1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(10px, 3fr) min-content 0.5fr;
    grid-row-gap: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-image{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center center;
}
.item-info{
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
.item-buy{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 7%;
}

.block-1 button{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 55%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    bottom: 7%;
    right: 7%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.price{
    padding-left: 3%;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.old-price{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 80%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
содержимое ячейки не уменьшается, а хотелось бы(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, подобные вещи лучше делать при помощи:

```
display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Просто потому, что это проще. Но если вам принципиально использовать `display: grid;`, то единственный вариант: перестраивать сетку. Это делается при помощи media-запросов. Побробнее про них [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
/* Адаптация для смартфонов. Один товар в ряд */
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .content {
        grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .block-1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Кстати запись по типу `<a><div> ... </div></a>` - неправильная. Если очень нужно сделать весь блок ссылкой, то хотя бы вот так: `<div><a> ... </a></div>`, `a {display: block}`.